# TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'entry'

Tags: python, django, for-loop, url-routing

I am in the middle of creating an encyclopedia project. On the home page is a list of entries and I want all the entries to be linked to their entry page.

Currently when I click on the link to an entry on the homepage, in this case the entry is called CSS, this is the error I get:

> TypeError at /wiki/CSS/
> entry() got an unexpected keyword argument 'entry'
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/CSS/

**views.py**

```
def css(request):
    return render(request, "entries/css.html", {
        "css_entry": util.get_entry("css")
    })

def entry(request):
    return render(request, entry, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entry": util.get_entry({"entry"})
})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("css/", views.css, name="css"),
    path("<str:entry>/", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

**index.html**

```
<ul>
 {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href = "{% url 'entry' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The frustrating thing is if I enter into the browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/CSS/ it works and the page loads fine but not when I click the link from the homepage. Plus, if I remove the entry argument leaving it as {% url 'entry' %} then the homepage stops working and I get the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /wiki/
> Reverse for 'CSS' not found. 'CSS' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/
> Django Version: 3.1.1
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Answer (score 1):

As your `entry` function take `entry`. Do:

```
def entry(request, entry):
    return render(request, entry, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entry": util.get_entry({"entry"})
    })
```

Comment: I tried what you said but unfortunately now when I click the link I'm getting an error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /wiki/CSS/. I'm guessing this means there's some problem with how my folders are arranged?

Comment: ``entries/css.html`` this should be``app_name/your_html_file``. Just like, what u did on entry function. Please check properly, there should be some spelling error or app_name error or sthg like that. And, chill bro you've got this :)